# What happens if some ground breaking, novel, Nobel prize winning ideas are posted in this website?

Tags: discussion

What happens if some ground breaking, novel, Nobel prize winning ideas are posted in this website?

Does the person posting the idea get credit ? Is there a risk of ideas being stolen from this website and plagiarized ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/34/2451

Comment: Content creators keep ownership of the content they post on SE. But I doubt _new_ physics would be posted here, new physics is usually not cooked up on a website.

Comment: @Manishearth [counterexample](http://timecube.com/).

Comment: @NickT: Are you joking?

Comment: @NickT are you serious ?

Comment: He's obviously joking here, it's a sarcastic way of pointing out the kind of "physics" that one finds "published" on the Internet. Legit physics  usually goes through peer review and mostly via a university

Answer (score 11):

1. For the most part you should not post new work here. This is a question and answer site, not a publication venue.
2. If you do, you  can rely on the site to establish priority. That's not ideal, but it will suffice.

Comment: But, new work should be closed right away because it is not mainstream physics.